# search for single or multiple occurrences of the samestring and edit next line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that sometimes has one occurrence or multiple occurrences of the same string. I am needing to search for one or more occurrences in the file and go to the next line and keep the values in that line but add a value to the end yet keeping the rest of the file intact. Here is what I have:

```
Line: 3, 0, "General Thunderstorm Risk"
 37.74, -87.17
 36.22, -85.50
 34.80, -85.41
 34.01, -85.72
 33.14, -86.64
 32.45, -88.05
 31.88, -89.68
 31.38, -91.39


Line: 3, 0, "General Thunderstorm Risk"
 29.04, -94.27
 29.74, -95.99
 30.91, -98.31
 31.68, -99.14
 32.45, -98.94
 33.58, -97.73
 35.11, -96.96
 36.63, -96.57


if grep "General Thunderstorm Risk" d1.txt; then
echo "General Thunderstorm Risk Detected"
POLYGON=`cat d1.txt | awk '/Line: 4, 0, \"General Thunderstorm Risk\"/{getline; print}'`
cat d1.txt | sed -e 's/Line: 4, 0, \"General Thunderstorm Risk\"/Polygon:/g' | sed -e "s/$POLYGON/$POLYGON, 0, 176, 80, 40/g" > day1
_colored.txt
fi
```

Comment: grep, awk, sed, cat ... hum! what output do you look for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply something to special lines in `sed`, you *address* them, like `/pattern/command` applies `command` to lines including the `pattern`.

If you want to apply a command to the next lines after the pattern line, first advance the line with `n` command.

Then, to append to the end of the line, use `s/$/whatever you want to append/` (the `$` stands for the line ending).

Now you need to combine those commands with `{}`, so the addressing is valid for both of them, and you and up with

```
sed '/General Thunderstorm Risk/{n;s/$/, 42/;}' yourfile.txt > out.txt
```

to append `, 42` to the line after the match. If that is not what you are looking for, please edit your question.